# Does delete masks put in Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

In the Hbase documentation (http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/versions.html), it says:

"*5.8.2.1. Deletes mask Puts*

*Deletes mask puts, even puts that happened after the delete was entered[18]. Remember that a delete writes a tombstone, which only disappears after then next major compaction has run. Suppose you do a delete of everything <= T. After this you do a new put with a timestamp <= T. This put, even if it happened after the delete, will be masked by the delete tombstone. Performing the put will not fail, but when you do a get you will notice the put did have no effect. It will start working again after the major compaction has run. These issues should not be a problem if you use always-increasing versions for new puts to a row. But they can occur even if you do not care about time: just do delete and put immediately after each other, and there is some chance they happen within the same millisecond.*"

However in our experimentation using Bigtable Hbase 1.0 API, delete does not mask puts. Can we confirm this is the expected behavior in Bigtable?

What we did is performing the following operations in order:

```
put data into column x with timestamp 10
put data into column x with timestamp 12
delete column x with timestamp 22
put data into column x with timestamp 17
put data into column x with timestamp 67
```

Then when we get column x we expect to see the cell with timestamp 67 only but we saw two cells with timestamps 17 and 67.

In our application, we prefer that delete masks put.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin,

Bigtable does not mask puts after delete if puts are issued after the deletion. The problem with masking puts is that puts will show up some time later after major compaction, which is a surprise, a unexpected result for users.
  Could you please describe your use case a bit so that we can better help you overcome this behavior which is not preferable to you?

Thanks!

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, as it doesn't fully address the question.

Comment: "Bigtable does not mask puts after delete if puts are issued after the deletion" is the answer.

Comment: Hi @kevin-si, thanks for your answer! I see, if the masked puts show up after compaction, then it's definitely not good. Just curious, why compaction won't remove the masked puts?

Comment: Our use case is quite simple. Basically for every column we have an incoming stream of puts and deletes, each with a timestamp, and they can arrive out of order. We want operations with newer timestamps always overwrite operations with older timestamps. For example, if a delete with timestamp 10 arrives first, then a later put with timestamp 5 should simply be ignored. So if deletes masks puts and puts are not recovered by compaction, then it's perfect for us. If deletes doesn't mask puts, then we are thinking about putting a dummy data for delete, so that it will masks puts during gets (cont)

Comment: (continued) do you think there might be a better way to handle this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Justin, Bigtable doesn't prevent users from writing cells with older timestamps. For example, if you deleted cells with versions <= 10, we do not prevent further writes with versions <= 10. You deletes and puts could be executed at most at the same time. What happens if a delete with version <=10 is executed now, and put with version 5 is executed 1 day later. It doesn't make sense for us to ignore that put with version 5 simply because there was a delete with version <= 10.

Comment: Two workarounds I can think of: 1) synchronize operations yourself so that operations with earlier timestamps will always be executed first. 2) put some delete marking information in one column, so that on put, you can check if this put should be allowed to go through. For example, on delete, set delete marker: [1 - 10], on put, check if the version it carries is outdated by checking against the delete marker: 5 is outdated compare to [ 1- 10], therefore cannot go through. Hope this works.